# How to create a Makefile or .pro file that runs a custom build event

Tags: linux, qt, makefile

I currently use a small program to process Qt form (.ui) files and automatically generate classes which have a common base class and use virtual functions to access the form elements. 
On windows, I run this tool as a custom build step on the ui form file. The only argument to the tool is the input filename.

To clarify, on Windows, Qt runs uic on the .ui file, creating a ui_filename.h file. I need to run my tool on *that* file.

How can/should I do this on linux? Ideally I'd build it into the .pro file, but I'm happy to edit the Makefile as well.

I'm not awesome at writing Makefiles so this may be very simple. I am happy to write the command manually for each ui_ or *.ui file but ideally it would happen automatically for all .ui files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed to write Makefiles manually. Makefiles that call custom external tool can be generated by `qmake` from the project file `.pro`.

It is needed to create a custom target using `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`. Then the main target should be set as denendent on that custom target (custom target name should be added to `PRE_TARGETDEPS`), for example [How to modify the PATH variable in Qt Creator's project file (.pro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122603/how-to-modify-the-path-variable-in-qt-creators-project-file-pro/33468475#33468475)

The tool should run after generation of the form headers, so the custom target should depend on that file `customtarget1.depends = ui_mainwindow.h`:

```
customtarget1.target = form_scanner
customtarget1.commands = tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh
customtarget1.depends = ui_mainwindow.h
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += customtarget1
PRE_TARGETDEPS += form_scanner
```

The above `qmake` commands create the following `Makefile` rules:

```
# the form header depends on mainwindow.ui
ui_mainwindow.h: ..\test\mainwindow.ui
<tab>#build command...

# form scanner depends on ui_mainwindow.h
form_scanner: ui_mainwindow.h
<tab>tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh

# the final target depends on form scanner
$(DESTDIR_TARGET): form_scanner ui_mainwindowm.h $(OBJECTS)
```

---

If there are many forms it is possible to create many custom targets or create one target that depends on all form files:

```
for (form, FORMS) {
    # autogenerated form headers are located in root of build directory
    FILE_NAME = $$basename(form)
    # prepend ui_ and replace ending .ui by .h
    FORM_HEADERS += ui_$$replace(FILE_NAME, .ui$, .h)
}

customtarget1.target = form_scanner
customtarget1.commands = tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh  
customtarget1.depends = $$FORM_HEADERS

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += customtarget1
PRE_TARGETDEPS += form_scanner
```

So, the command `tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh` is executed only when all form headers are generated.

It is also possible to run the shell script from the project directory `$$PWD` and pass as command line arguments the form header file names:

```
customtarget1.commands = $$PWD/tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh $$FORM_HEADERS
```

Now that shell script can run some command for each form header `tool_win_bat_or_linux_shell.sh`:

```
# for each command line argument
for file in "$@"
do
    echo "$file"
    ls -l $file
done
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks like just the ticket. I haven't checked it yet but it certainly makes more sense than editing the Makefile manually